# Overwriting content of textfile in assets folder in Android project

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a file named `counter.txt` in the assets folder of my Android project. At runtime I want to overwrite the content of the file. But it's not reflecting. How can I fix this problem?

I have used the below code.

```
String FILENAME = "counter.txt";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you can't `write/update` in the `assets` folder. The only thing you can do is `read`.

Comment: so is there any other way of storing and updating the data in android.....i tried using Shared Preferences and i was successful in storing my data but when i choose to "Clear Data" form Application settings,the saved data is getting deleted. So i tired storage using text files in assets folder and u answered its not possible so there an alternative solution???

Comment: If you Clear Data, it will clear all your application data. You can write files on the SDCard.

Comment: i want to store confidential data and storing it on SDCard is to risky as it is removable media. I also tried disabling "Clear Data" button but its too not happening. Can u help me in dis??

Comment: SDCard can't be secure, you can encrypt your data before writing in the file, but then to you won't be able to restrict user to delete your file.

Answer (score -1):

More precisely, you can't make any changes to the 'asset' folder at runtime through your code, but after you compile your code and get the [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file, you can unzip it, change the contents of the 'asset' folder and zip all the files to APK again.

However, you must sign the APK file again to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use class *[SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)* in such a case to store all your confidential but frequently updated counters.